# Resume fails on Dell E6510

Tags: 10.10, resume

This is quite similar to several other posts.
System was running 10.04 without problems for several months.

Recently upgraded to 10.10 and have not been able to resume from closing lid on laptop since. Have to reboot from forced power down. No other posts I have seen have suggested an approach to solving the problem.

Comment: I am suffering of the same problem here, this is very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Try update system maybe new update will help. Maybe you havent updated system for long time. Also googling problem may help find slow fix. 
I googled and found this is bug thats now beeing in fixing process so maybe even after month it will be fixed. U can help fixing by coding or commenting
https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/605176
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/Laptop/Maverick/Reports/DellLatitudeE6510

Comment: It looks like its been fixed. Try now with updates check my link

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Asus K52F. The only working solution I found at Code Central [Fix Ubuntu 10.10 Suspend/Hibernate Not Working Bug](http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug) .

Good luck.